# Inserted rows is not updating in database through JDBC

Tags: oracle, jdbc, insert, sql-update, commit

hi am trying to insert values into SQL database using jdbc. Current code able to connect and query sql DB. am using executeupdate to insert the values .this code is not giving any errors.but values are not getting inserted into SQL DB,even though i tired commiting the code after and before executing. how can i insert values into DB???

```
    import java.io.IOException;       
   import java.io.PrintWriter;       
   import java.sql.Connection;       
   import java.sql.DriverManager;       
   import java.sql.SQLException;       
   import java.sql.Statement;       
   import oracle.jdbc.driver.*;       

   import javax.servlet.ServletException;       
   import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;       
   import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;       
   import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;       


   public class Servlet1 extends HttpServlet {       
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)       
throws ServletException,IOException       
{       
    String p1=request.getParameter("param1");       
    String p2=request.getParameter("param2");       
    String p3=request.getParameter("param3");       
    String p4=request.getParameter("param4");       
    String p5=request.getParameter("param5");       
    String sql="INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES (Id,Name,Post,Salary,Location)  VALUES('" + p1 + "','" + p2 + " ','" + p3 + "','" + p4 + " ','" + p5 + " ')";       
    try       
    {       
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");       
    }       
    catch(ClassNotFoundException ex)       
    {       
        ex.printStackTrace();       
    }       
    Connection con=null;       
    Statement stmt=null;       
    try       
    {       
        con =        DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/XE","test","Gari!2563");       
        stmt=con.createStatement();       
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);       
         con.setAutoCommit(true);       
    }       
    catch(SQLException ex)       
    {       
        ex.printStackTrace();       
    }       
    finally       
    {       
        try       
        {       
        if(stmt!=null)       
        {       
            stmt.close();       
            stmt=null;       
        }       
    }       
    catch(SQLException ex)       
    {       
        ex.printStackTrace();       
    }       
    try       
    {       
        if(con!=null)       
        {       
            con.close();       
            con=null;       
        }       
    }       
    catch(SQLException ex)       
    {       
        ex.printStackTrace();       
    }       
}       
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();       
out.println("done");       
}
```

}

I AM USING jdk1.7  ,Oracle DB XE 11.2.0.  Apache tomcat 7  eclipse juno EE edition.

Comment: You asked this question before ([here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17318449/jdbc-connecting-with-oracle-11g)). Next time please update the existing question instead of asking a new one. I have voted to close the old one as you provide a bit more detail here.

Comment: ok ,i will.didnt knew dat i m new here.But help me out with this wasted almost 6 hours.

Comment: Have you checked the logs of your application server, you are printing out the stacktrace and then ignoring the exception, it could very well mean you did not execute a query at all

Comment: so,what actually i have to change in this code?

Comment: Check the logs of your application server, or change all `ex.printStackTrace()` to `throw new ServletException(ex)` and see if you get an exception

Comment: while replacing ex.printStackTrace() to throw new ServletException(ex) i got error HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.          i was trying to access the DB thorugh a html file n servlet for connection

Comment: Problem identified, now you need to fix it. Update the question with this exception and specify which application server you are using.

Comment: Well, then you are missing a .jar file in your path for the JDBC driver.  What version of oracle are you using?  You can download the drivers here - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html

Comment: still its not inserting any row,i got pissed of! i imported ojdbc6.jar,servlet-api.jar,tomcat-jdbc.jar into external libraries of build path,its not even showing any error simply printing done,i am using jdk 1.7,tomcat 7 eclipse juno EEedition,Oracle DB XE 11.2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the code is wrong.

If you want to use autocommit mode, then it should be set before the query is executed (typically, after the getConnection()) - not once the query has been executed.

If you don't want to use autocommit, then you need an explicit con.commit() after the statement has been executed. You may want to have a look [at the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html) for more information.

Since you have fixed your exceptions due to missing jdbc driver, it should work now.

Comment: thanx sir i just moved con.setAutoCommit(true); before connection and it really worked all the rows are getting inserted in DB.